# Punctuation in a compound sentence describing two parallel processes

Tags: punctuation, commas, compounds

Do I need a comma at the end of a clause that presents some action that is happening simultaneously with the action that will be described in the main clause?

For example:

> When kids' passive vocabulary is **growing,** they start
>   understanding things and then just naturally want to respond to what
>   is being presented or discussed in the class.

Do I need a comma after the word "growing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma in that position helps understanding. It stops you from trying to understand "they naturally start..." as being an object of "understanding", and it matches the intonation and rhythm that a speaker would use.

So you should use a comma at that point.

(Also, the sentence uses "naturally" twice, which is rather poor style)